# Issues installing MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I have been trying to install the MEAN stack using the following tutorial:

http://www.bossable.com/303/install-mean-stack/#comment-1526

I am using webstorm and MongoDB.

However I have been unsuccessful and I keep getting errors. Everytime I connect to localhost:3000 I get the following error:

```
   C:\meanproject>grunt
   Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
   >> 55 files lint free.

   Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
   >> 2 files lint free.

   Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
   Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
   Running "watch" task
   Waiting...
   [nodemon] v1.2.1
   [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js          config/**/*.js app/*
    */*.js
   [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
    Debugger listening on port 5858
   Application loaded using the "development" environment configuration
   { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson']   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

  js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
  { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson']  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

  js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
  MEAN.JS application started on port 3000
    C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection
   \base.js:246
    throw message;
          ^
Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions
at C:\meanproject\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:169:23
at C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.
js:1499:46
at C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.
js:1632:20
 at  C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cur
sor.js:170:22
 at  C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cur
    sor.js:714:39
    at Cursor.close   (C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\l
 ib\mongodb\cursor.js:1009:5)
 at commandHandler (C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb
    \lib\mongodb\cursor.js:714:21)
    at C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.
    js:1905:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler  (C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modul
   es\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:453:41)
   at   C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\con
   nection\server.js:488:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\m
    ongodb\lib\mongodb\responses\mongo_reply.js:68:5)
     at null.<anonymous>  (C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongo
 db\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:446:20)
at emit (events.js:107:17)
at null.<anonymous> (C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongo
db\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:207:13)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\meanproject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mon
godb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:440:22)
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: check your mongod service is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the mongodb.exe file first. After successfully starting mongodb, you need to navigate into your project folder and run 'grunt'. If it shows you a error list of modules not found, you need to install those modules globally with npm. That will solve the problem for you. However, please note that bossable.com tutorial is for 0.3 mean stack boiler plate. They have upgraded their version to 0.4.1 now. Follow the [Meanjs documentation](http://meanjs,org)
for latest information.